# Return sum of values of nodes..but we cant add any value since there is no variable inside the interface

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;


public class BetterProgrammerTask {

    // Please do not change this interface
    public static interface Node {
        int getValue();
        List<Node> getChildren();
    }


    public static int getLevelSum(Node root, int N) {
        /*
          Please implement this method to
          traverse the tree and return the sum of the values (Node.getValue()) of all nodes
          at the level N in the tree.
          Node root is assumed to be at the level 1. All its children are level 2, etc.
         */
    }
}
```

It's a task from BetterProgrammer.com and I'm stuck here. I just want few hints 
like what means by traversing the tree and whats the second parameter of getLevelSum() method?

Comment: Please do some basic research on trees and their traversal e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal

Comment: And perhaps on interfaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`N` is the "depth" of the level - the root node is 1, it's children are 2, their children are 3, etc. Note that the given `BetterProgrammingTask` is a **class**, not an **interface**, so you can add member variables (not that you'd need them) and implementations.

This method could be implemented by recursing over the nodes and checking the depth:

```
public static int getLevelSum(Node root, int N) {
    // Safe guard, probably redundant.
    if (N <= 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("N must be positive");
    }

    // We're at the level we want to sum, return the value
    if (N == 1) {
        return root.getValue();
    }

    int sum = 0;
    for (Node child : root.getChildren()) {
        sum += getLevelSum (child, N - 1);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Some hints :

1. This exercise calls for a recursive implementation
2. if N == 1 you return the value of the node and don't care about the children.
3. if N > 1, `getLevelSum(node,N)` == the sum of `getLevelSum(child,N-1)` for all the children of that node.
4. As you can see, the second parameter is used to determine if you reached the level you are requested to find the sum of the nodes for.